# Disable "smart" window switch on debian fluxbox

Tags: debian, windows, fluxbox

On my debian fluxbox there is a feature, that switches to the window the cursor points at without clicking (it just automatically switches making it difficult to stay within one window). How can I disable that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is the "Focus Model", currently yours is set to "Mouse Focus". [As of version 1.0rc3 Fluxbox has the following options:](https://fluxbox-users.narkive.com/1dOBJbOU/focus-follows-mouse-and-maximizing-problems-in-fluxbox-1-0rc3)

> - *Click To Focus*:
>     click to focus windows
> - *Mouse Focus*:
>     window focus follows mouse
> - *Click Tab Focus*:
>     click to focus tabs
> - *Mouse Tab Focus*:
>     tab focus follows mouse

[The current Fluxbox package available for Debian Stretch is version 1.3.5-2](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fluxbox)

[Looking to the documentation](http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox.php#_focus_model), you can see that you can change these options in the configuration menu, located under the root menu of Fluxbox.

```
Root Menu → Configuration → Focus Model → Click To Focus [Or whatever option you desire]
```

You will have to restart FluxBox for this change to take effect.